# Table or view not found exception when writing to Hive

Tags: apache-spark

I'm saving a dataframe to Hive using saveAsTable("schema.table") but it throws a org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found exception. This happens with both "overwrite" and "append" mode flags.

The target table does indeed not exist, checked using

```
scala> spark.catalog.tableExists("table_name")
```

Per my understanding the mode flag controls the behaviour depending on whether the target table exists or not. So normally this is irrelevant for the issue at hand. Thinking the issue is with the table creation itself but I don't know how to investigate this.

Thank you!

Comment: You have submitted Spark not configured with hive. Spark has to have hive-site-xml in classpath (normally in conf folder). Add it via --files /path/to/hive-site.xml

Comment: Update the question with how you are creating your sparksession instance.

Answer (score 1):

*#incase you want pyspark/pysparksql*

Spark saveAsTable is not much compatible with hive table.
I would suggest to create a temptable in spark and after that load data into hive table using CTAS.

> Df.createOrReplaceTempView("mytempTable")

> sqlContext.sql("create table mytable as select * from mytempTable")

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a standard case of being stupid: the error had nothing to do with the table creation, I was attempting some table statistics on the actual table I was trying to create before actually creating it.

Best,
SD_